# oracle cast needed if variable has already been defined with the right type?

Tags: oracle, casting, plsql, oracle11g

In this stored proc snippet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PORTAL_OWNER.searchAtTransfers_prc_xmltype (
   usercredential      IN     VARCHAR,
   doc_result_cursor      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
..
..
   docExtTable     DOC_TABLETYPE;//user defiend type that is a collection of below Type.
   docExtRecord    DOC_ROWTYPE;//user defined type
BEGIN
    SELECT DOC_ROWTYPE (extractvalue (value (t), 'transfers/userRequestId')
         , extractvalue (value (t), 'transfers/fromAccount/acctId')      
    BULK COLLECT INTO docExtTable
   FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (response, '//transferSearchResponse/transfers'))) t;

   OPEN doc_result_cursor FOR 
        SELECT * FROM TABLE (CAST (docExtTable AS DOC_TABLETYPE));

   COMMIT;
END;
```

My questions is: Why we need to `CAST (docExtTable AS DOC_TABLETYPE` when `docExtTable` has been defined already as `DOC_TABLETYPE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But do we need to CAST it?

When Oracle first introduced the TABLE() function back in Oracle 8.0 the CAST was mandatory.  However, Oracle recognised the tautology some while back, and CAST is usually optional in later versions.

You've tagged your question as `[oracle11g]` .  So what happens if you remove the CAST?  That is, I would expect this to work:

```
from table (SELECT * FROM docExtTable);
```

Comment: so i should try:SELECT * FROM docExtTable; Right?